# VBA Date as integer

Tags: excel, vba, date, datetime

is there a way to get the underlying integer for `Date` function in VBA ? I'm referring to the integer stored by Excel to describe dates in memory in terms of number of days (when time is included it can be a float then I guess). I'm only interest in the integer part though. Is there just another function for that ?

For example, for today() I'd like to be able to get back 40877..

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Date is not an Integer in VB(A), it is a Double.

You can get a Date's value by passing it to `CDbl()`.

```vb
CDbl(Now())      ' 40877.8052662037
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/1900-and-1904-date-system):

> #### The 1900 Date System
>
> In the 1900 date system, the first day that is supported is January 1,
>   1900. When you enter a date, the date is converted into a serial number that represents the number of elapsed days starting with 1 for
>   January 1, 1900. For example, if you enter July 5, 1998, Excel
>   converts the date to the serial number 35981.

So in the 1900 system, `40877.805...` represents 40,876 days after January 1, 1900 (29 November 2011), and ~80.5% of one day (~19:19h). There is a setting for 1904-based system in Excel, numbers will be off when this is in use (that's a per-workbook setting).

To get the integer part, use

```vb
Int(CDbl(Now())) ' 40877
```

which would return a <strike>Long</strike>Double with no decimal places (i.e. what `Floor()` would do in other languages).

Using `CLng()` or `Round()` would result in rounding, which will return a "day in the future" when called after 12:00 noon, so don't do that.

Comment: Int(CDbl(Now())) does not return a long, it returns a double.  The double's value just happens to represent an integer, but it's data type is still double.

Comment: @phoog: `TypeName(VarType(Int(CDbl(Now())))) = "Long"` on my system

Comment: @Tomalek of course, because `VarType(Int(CDbl(Now())))` returns 5, which is the value of `vbDouble`, but is itself a `Long`.  Try `TypeName(Int(CDbl(Now())))`.

Comment: If you use `Date` instead of `Now` all these part day problems go away - `Date` (the function not the data type) returns the day with no time component.

Comment: @JonEgerton not to mention that the OP was asking about the Date function in the first place, not the Now function.

Comment: @Tomalak This was a great answer - to remind us the format is double, not integer - a common misconception and how `Int()` is like `Math.floor` (JavaScript).  Saved me, too!  Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Just use `CLng(Date)`.

Note that you need to use `Long` not `Integer` for this as the value for the current date is > 32767

Comment: Indeed I didnt think of the Long/Integer issue ! Thanks !

Comment: CLng will round afternoon values up to the next day.

Comment: @phoog. I've used `Date` not `Now`. `Date` has no time component, therefore `CLng` is fine and safe.

Comment: @JonEgerton of course.  I overlooked that.  I didn't cast the downvote, so I can't remove it :(  I did add an upvote, however :)

Comment: @phoog: no worries, that makes me net +8!

Answer (score 1):

```
Public SUB test()
    Dim mdate As Date
    mdate = now()
    MsgBox (Round(CDbl(mdate), 0))
End SUB
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bellow code example for date string like mdate and Now() like toDay, you can also calculate deference between both date like Aging

```
Public Sub test(mdate As String)
    Dim toDay As String
    mdate = Round(CDbl(CDate(mdate)), 0)
    toDay = Round(CDbl(Now()), 0)
    Dim Aging as String
    Aging = toDay - mdate
    MsgBox ("So aging is -" & Aging & vbCr & "from the date - " & _
    Format(mdate, "dd-mm-yyyy")) & " to " & Format(toDay, "dd-mm-yyyy"))
End Sub
```

NB: Used `CDate` for convert Date String to Valid Date

I am using this in Office 2007 :)

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original question of how to get a date portion of a date that doesn't flip to the following day if the time portion is after noon.

Dim JustDate As Date

JustDate = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Date_and_Time_Value, 0)